# NullReferenceException In Partial View Page

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-3-areas

Thanks for reading this.

I have no idea why this is throwing a NullReferenceException in _GetDate.cshtml:

```
<legend>For This @Model.lob.ToUpper() Please Enter Date Range</legend>
```

SomeController pass model --> Index.cshtml -->  @Html.Partial("_GetDate", Model)

Also, when I break one line above in the intermediate Window I could see the value for @Model.lob.

Here's the stack trace:

```
System.NullReferenceException was unhandled by user code
Message=Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
Source=App_Web_l250s0ch
StackTrace:
    at ASP._Page_Views_Shared__GetDate_cshtml.Execute() in c:\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\Web\SomeProject\SomeProject\Views\Shared\_GetDate.cshtml:line 7
    at System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy()
    at System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage.ExecutePageHierarchy()
    at System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy(WebPageContext pageContext, TextWriter writer, WebPageRenderingBase startPage)
    at System.Web.Mvc.RazorView.RenderView(ViewContext viewContext, TextWriter writer, Object instance)
    at System.Web.Mvc.BuildManagerCompiledView.Render(ViewContext viewContext, TextWriter writer)
    at System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper.RenderPartialInternal(String partialViewName, ViewDataDictionary viewData, Object model, TextWriter writer, ViewEngineCollection viewEngineCollection)
    at System.Web.Mvc.Html.PartialExtensions.Partial(HtmlHelper htmlHelper, String partialViewName, Object model, ViewDataDictionary viewData)
    at System.Web.Mvc.Html.PartialExtensions.Partial(HtmlHelper htmlHelper, String partialViewName, Object model)
    at ASP._Page_Views_Balance_GetDate_cshtml.Execute() in c:\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\Web\SomeProject\SomeProject\Views\Balance\GetDate.cshtml:line 22
    at System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy()
    at System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage.ExecutePageHierarchy()
    at System.Web.WebPages.StartPage.RunPage()
    at System.Web.WebPages.StartPage.ExecutePageHierarchy()
    at System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy(WebPageContext pageContext, TextWriter writer, WebPageRenderingBase startPage)
    at System.Web.Mvc.RazorView.RenderView(ViewContext viewContext, TextWriter writer, Object instance)
    at System.Web.Mvc.BuildManagerCompiledView.Render(ViewContext viewContext, TextWriter writer)
    at System.Web.Mvc.ViewResultBase.ExecuteResult(ControllerContext context)
    at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResult(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult)
    at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass1c.<InvokeActionResultWithFilters>b__19()
    at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilter(IResultFilter filter, ResultExecutingContext preContext, Func`1 continuation)
InnerException:
```

Here's GetDate.cshtml (line 22 = @Html.Partial("_GetDate", Model)):

```
@model SomeProject.Models.DateParameter

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "GetDate";
}

@section script{
 @Content.Script("/UI/jquery.ui.core.js", Url)
 @Content.Script("/UI/jquery.ui.widget.js", Url)
 @Content.Script("/UI/jquery.ui.datepicker.js", Url)
 @Content.Script("MyCustomScript.js", Url)
}

@*<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/UI/jquery-ui-1.8.18.custom.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>*@
@*<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/UI/jquery.ui.core.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/UI/jquery.ui.widget.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/UI/jquery.ui.datepicker.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>*@
@*@Content.ScriptinUI("jquery.ui.datepicker.js", Url)*@

<div id="table_div">

    @Html.Partial("_GetDate", Model)

</div>
```

Here's "_GetDate":

```
@model SomeProject.Models.DateParameter
<h2>@Model.lob.ToUpper() </h2>
    <table id="MainTable">
    <tr class="DatePicker"> <td>
    @Model.lob.ToUpper() 
    </td></tr>
</table>
```

Here's code from the Controller:

```
    public ActionResult GetDate(string lob)
    {
        var model = new DateParameter();
        model.lob = lob;
        ViewBag.lob = lob;
        return View(model);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult GetDate(FormCollection values, DateParameter newDateParameter)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            TempData["MyDate"] = newDateParameter;                
            return RedirectToAction("Listing");
        }
        else
        {
            return View(newDateParameter);
        }
    }
```

Might as well include the class for DateParameter:

```
public class DateParameter : IValidatableObject
{
    [Required]
    [StringLength(3)]
    public virtual string lob { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [DataType(DataType.DateTime)]
    [DisplayName("Start Date")]
    public virtual DateTime DateStart { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [DataType(DataType.DateTime)]
    [DisplayName("End Date")]
    public virtual DateTime DateEnd { get; set; }

    //VALIDATE DATES

    public IEnumerable<ValidationResult> Validate(ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
        //SET ERROR NEXT TO THE FIELD
        var field = new[] { "DateEnd" };

        if (DateEnd > DateTime.Now.AddDays(1))
        {
            yield return new ValidationResult("The End Date Cannot Be Greater Than Today", field);
        }
    }
}
```

Any idea how to return the string in @Model.lob in the partial view page?

TIA!

Comment: Can you show the stack trace and relevant code?

Comment: I'm sure that the `Model` you're passing in is `null` or `.case` is `null`

Comment: off-topic: `case` is a reserved word in C#. It's an extremely poor naming choice for a property. The convention in C# dictates that property names must start with a capital letter.

Comment: Hi Darin, ok, it's not 'case', but it's 'lob': Model.lob.

I will provide the stack trace in one min ...

Comment: sorry it looks messy; I'm learning how to format in comments ..

Comment: Comments are not supposed to be used to post code snippets. Please update your question to include this information and remove it from the comments.

Comment: @hunter; it's not null b/c i can see it in the intermediate Window in the _GetDate page. Thanks!

Comment: if we cannot figure this out I won't use Partial page and the worst case is hard code in 'lob'... btw, this is for work and I'm using my helloworld as my test ground and then moving everything over to the project solution. Thanks.

Comment: Can you show us the code where you return the (Partial)View including the Model from your controller?

Comment: @Silvermind; did I get you what u asked? Sorry if I don't understand. Thanks!

Comment: I have no problems running the code, so I guess I must be doing something wrong. (Or right). Something must be null. Note that the intermediate Window can also show data related to something else with the same name. Hover over the property that throw's the exception (before it throw's ofcourse) and check whether it's null using the hover/watch mode.

Comment: @Silvermind .. thanks for running the code .. So, set breakpoint  --> <h2>@Model.lob.ToUpper() </h2> <--
Run app and when it stops on that line hovering over it shows null for lob, but not date. Then pressing 'F11' it doesn't jump to the next line, but there was a quick flash and it's back to the same line and this time 'lob' has a value when hover over it. \
Press F11 again goes to the next line (@using (Html.BeginForm()) {) F11 again and you get the null exception....  Does this make sense? ..

Comment: The problem you describe could occur because you have two actions with the same name `GetDate`. Perhaps the controller doesn't know which action to call when passing more than one variable and calls them both. Try putting a breakpoint in both actions and see if they both get hit with one post. The action decorated with the `HttpPost` attribute could give you an invalid `.lob`, because it is not assigned there. It would explain a flashing line because there are two threads parsing your view and only one has the proper value assigned. Pressing F11 is probably jumping from thread to thread.

Comment: Pressing F11 is probably jumping from thread to thread which would at one point indicate a valid value in the intermediate window and at the next press it could be invalid in the other thread.

Comment: @Silvermind .. That makes sense; good observation. I will rename and see if that will work. Thanks again.

Comment: @Silvermind; Changed '_GetDate' to _SetDate' that didn't work.
so set breakpoints all over and in the controller's action GetDate (without the 'HttpPost') it seems that it gets called twice .. meaning the first time 'lob' is null; then F11 + quick flash .. it comes back and this time 'lob' has a value ... Tried it with 'HttpGet' and the same behavior ... maybe I will try rebooting ...

Comment: @Silvermind; you won't believe it, but rebooting did the trick.
It's strange that it would do this controller (GetDate) action --> (GetDate) View and repeat .. Thanks for the help @Silvermind. BTW, how do I 'accept' an answer .. I don't see the big check-mark.

Comment: Don't mention it. Perhaps a weird bug of some sort. However you should post your own findings as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For what it's worth rebooting corrected the issue. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Is the @Model.lob set?

If not, calling a method on it will throw the reported exception.

Comment: hi, yes it's set from the querystring. Thanks for asking.